# nginx and php | can't resolve hostname and make connection with FQDN

Tags: nginx, php, hostname, resolve, getaddrinfo

I don't know what can cause this problem, nginx configs or php or anything else but :

I can not make connection when **host value** for these php functions listed below is set to **FQDN** like **http://www.domain.com or www.domain.com** but **problem all goes away** if i put hostname ip for instance **192.2.8.1** .

```
 ex: @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10) 
    won't establish connection when $host = "www.somedomain.com"
    successfully connects when $host = "192.2.2.1"
```

listed functions suffering form the same problem so far

- @fsockopen
- @file_get_contents
- phpmailer can't send email through SMTP when host is "www.somedomain.com" but succesfully send mail when host is "192.2.2.1"

all of those were working perfectly before i point my FQDN to my server and when i was testing 
plus it all works both with ip and domain from my pc running wammp server and on same app, on same codes
i'm not 100% sure but i guess this problem raised after i pointed my domain and DNS to server ?!

**Note :** this case is related to server configs and i have provided php references to better describe the case

' downvoters can now relax, i have completely changed the description ' .

Comment: Did you check the obvious? What is in your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: this is my resolv.conf values :                           nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 209.244.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok ! Finally after a week struggling with this issue :

First of all it seems to be a very popular problem for a century !

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11058

https://www.google.com/search?hl=es&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=php+php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed&meta=&gws_rd=ssl

Some ppl have found individual solutions at their own but definitely it's not a PHP bug .

What this issue can cover :

- If you can't connect with **@fsockopen**
- If can't get content with **@file_get_contents**
- If your php script can't send email or connect to **SMTP Server**
- If you can't ping your domain or getting **can't find ping: Non-existent domain**
- If you can't knock your server ip and getting **getaddrinfo() failed**
- If you have problem with **php_network_getaddresses** directly
- If your Wordpress throws error **Unable to Connect to tcp://mydomain.com:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.**

--Things that can cause these problems-------------------------------------------------

[X]
First thing to check is to check your **php.ini** and make sure these attributes are enabled

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

```
allow_url_include = On
```

[X]

Create a phpinfo() file  [ *phpinfofile.com* *just in case* ] and check if these extensions are enabled

```
OpenSSL
```

```
Socket
```

Especially for windows user running xammp or wammp by disabling PHP_OpenSSL extension you might be unable to connect through @fsockopen

[X]
Now the important part, is to go after **resolv.conf**
Open your resolv.conf by running

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

1. Delete comments, if there is a comment line at the start completely remove it
2. Make a change to nameservers, even if they are fine just change the order of them, this helps to purge DNS cache if there's an old cache

[X]
Strongly make sure your **/etc/resolv.conf is not a symlink** pointing to some directories commonly at /run/resolvconf/ or etc ..
you can run

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

and see what the result is, if it's something like

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root ` ` /etc/resolv.conf --------> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

If you have an ftp access go download your /etc/resolv.conf then rename the current one on your server to something line /etc/resolv.conf-----bk ( to have it just for backup ) and then upload the one you downloaded from your system to server /etc/
Or if you don't have access to ftp
run these commands

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
put your nameservers on new file 

ex:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

and save it by pressing Ctr + X  then Type "Y" and hit enter
chmod a+r /etc/resolv.conf
```

*In this case my issue was that !*

[X]
Make sure your reslv.conf is accessible to all users

```
chmod a+r /etc/resolv.conf
```

The result should be

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root <size> <date>
```

after running **ls -la /etc/resolv.conf**

[X]
Next Run

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Find the **dns-nameservers** and make sure nameservers seem fine ( preferably put whatever nameservers that are on your /etc/resolv.conf file  - ex: **dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4**

*That's all that i've discovered for this issue so far , i tried it to be understandable for anyone, sorry for annoying references to things you well know 
 If anybody else have something more for this matter please share it .*

Answer (score 3):

Nginx doesn't use the system's resolver. You have to define the resolver using the `resolver` directive.

Configures name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into addresses, for example:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

Answer (score 0):

due to amount of information you provided it's really hard to help you, but I'd start by checking `/etc/resolv.conf` and check each of `nameserver` to see if it works properly:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search XXX.XXX
nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

you can use `dig`, `host` and `nslookup`.

Comment: if any specific information you need please ask

Comment: @Timberland judging from amount of downvotes, your question could use some better description, try providing us _MORE_ information and not less if you still want us to help you out. It sounds like you're mixing several issues into one question, try to separate them.

Comment: no i am not mixing anything they are altogether side-effects of one single problem , maybe some of them are not necessary to mention and might confuse you but it's just One single problem, as long as i can't guess what that could be , nginx or php-fpm config or .. i gave those examples . but i take your advise and try to clean up the description a bit